# Uncaught ReferenceError: QRCode is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

I tried to implement a QRCode in my HTML-Template:

```
 <div id="qrcode">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), 'http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie');
        </script>
    </div>
```

In my qrcode.min.js I have this:

```
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
width: 128,
height: 128,
colorDark : "#000000",
colorLight : "#ffffff",
correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```

But I still get this error and the QRCode don't show off..

Here is my path:

```
<script "type=text/javascript" src="qrcode.min.js"></script>
```

**Solved**

I solved the issue.

The problem was that I integrated :

```
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",  
width: 128,
height: 128,
colorDark : "#000000",
colorLight : "#ffffff",
correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```

But I never integrated the function "QRCode".
https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/blob/master/qrcode.min.js

There is a really good documentation about the implementation of QRCodes. 
I needed this function in my qrcode.min.js and now it is working.

Comment: Have you referenced the qrcode script in your html like `<script src="/path/to/qrcode.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: Make sure your capitalization is correct, since JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes I did I get 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I checked my capitalization often anyway I copy it from http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

Comment: Make sure the path to `qrcode.min.js` is working properly.

Comment: I edited it, it should be correct.

Comment: You have two places where you call `QRCode`, but I can't see any where you define it.